# Avoid Seconds and milliseconds part from where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using below sql to fetch records from a table created 1 minute back

```
    SELECT Id,OrderNumber FROM ActivationRequest 
    WHERE Processed =0 AND 
    DateCreated <= DATEADD(minute,Convert(int,-1), GETDATE())
```

DateCreated  : A column of data type Datetime and at time of insert long datettime value with seconds and milliseconds is getting inserted to it

While performing selct operation can we avoid the seconds and milliseconds part in some way ?

Example: DateCreated  value 2018-12-07 07:08:41.703

But when i make the above select sql at  2018-12-07 07:08:51.597 , it returned 0 records back. Since the millisecond part of datetime is .597 only

So how can i avoid the seconds and milliseconds part and simply check hour and minute part in the where condition.
I need to fetch all records added in the last minute irrespective of seconds and milliseconds value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may round to the nearest minute:

```
SELECT Id, OrderNumber
FROM ActivationRequest 
WHERE
    Processed = 0 AND 
    DateCreated <= DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0);
```

Here is a demo showing the logic behind the calculus above used with `GETDATE()`:

### Demo

The above query should have reasonably good performance because it can use an index on `DateCreated`.

Comment: this will round to the next minute only,How can we make it to the previous minute

Comment: confused over choosing this approach or Ranjith suggestion. Any suggestion on perfomace impact

Comment: @JibinMathew `FORMAT` tends to have poor performance, but does that really matter to you here?

Comment: 2 Reasons for not picking the answer from @Ranjith are mainly that it will return the wrong result for several reasons and secondly using a format on a column while comparing will impact on performance seriously

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
SELECT Id, OrderNumber
FROM ActivationRequest 
WHERE
Processed = 0 AND 
FORMAT(DateCreated,'dd:mm:yyyy:hh:mm') = FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd:mm:yyyy:hh:mm');
```

Comment: This will return the arbitrary result. And even if you fix it to **<=** and **dd:MM:yyyy:hh:mm** it return the wrong result. **08:12:2017:09:51** is not larger than **07:12:2018:09:51** which your query claim